# Who bitcoin get the transaction fee? part2

Tags: transaction-fees

I know this question asked before, but the answers give still make no sense to me.  The most common answer is "the transaction fee goes to the miner" I'm in a small mining community and nobody ever received a fee. So I'm curious who is are the people and companies who really receive the fees, because this seems to be real real big business.

Comment: Please update your original question, or post a comment there. This shouldn't be a separate question.

Comment: You could also link to the question whose answers you don't understand, and then ask for clarification about a specific point.  That would help people know what you specifically don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction fees go to the entity that created the block. The transaction fee is paid out as part of the coin generation transaction along with the block subsidy. This means that the entity that created the block receives both the block subsidy and the transaction fees simultaneously. Currently, the entities that create blocks are mining pools, not individual miners (although individual miners could create a block, it just an extremely long time). The mining pool will then take what was paid out in the block and distribute it to the miners participating in the pool according to whatever internal rules that they follow. This means that miners will be paid less Bitcoin at a time than if they solo mined, but will be paid more consistently. This payout may include transaction fees, but it really all depends on the pool operator to determine how much each participating miner gets paid.

Comment: ok thank you for this clear answer. So the pool determined the fee, and a wallet picks a pool. Thus if I want the fee for my little pool, I need to convince a wallet maker, that they pick my pool, right?

Comment: No. Wallets and wallet makers are not involved in this whatsoever. The transaction fee cannot be given to any specific miner or mining pool.  The mining pool does not determine the transaction fees either. The transaction fee goes to the entity that mines the block, which is usually a mining pool. This means that the pool operator actually receives all of the money, and it is his responsibility to distribute the funds to the miners participating in the pool. Your mining pool is receiving transaction fees for each block it is mining, just that you as an individual may not be paid them.

Answer (score 3):

Miners receive the fees. Really.

If you're not getting fees, either you mine in a mining pool that doesn't keep track of fees and block reward separately, or you mine for a mining pool that doesn't distribute transaction fees to its miners, or you aren't including transactions in your blocks.

So either 1) you get the transaction fee, but you don't know it, or 2) the pool keeps the transaction fee, or 3) the pool includes no transactions and therefore gets no fees.